# Getting Hydration Failed errors in shopify when building the first app

Tags: shopify-app

I am learning how to code an Shopify app. I wanted to build first app and I started following this tutorial : https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create

I used npm init @Shopify/app@latest to create first app, then moved to that directory using cd .\first-app\ then I used npm run dev App looks and works fine with UI but on console I am getting lots of errors. Here are few of them.

1. Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
2. There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
3. vendors-node_modules_bugsnag_js_browser_notifier_js-node_modules_shopify_monorail_lib_monorai-fdaebc-b7c7bc61031d801d7cdf29f30133708999e0fe454a161247422ecc3e28c64ef8.js:2
4. Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error completing request. A network failure may have prevented the request from completing. Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

And few more, I did set up the ngrok tunnel and it is working fine.

I might be missing something, any help or pointing me to right direction is appriciated

Trying to build my first app on Shopify going through their documentation using : https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Shopify team [has an issue open](https://github.com/Shopify/hydrogen/issues/505) for these warnings / errors. They have identified that the errors are coming from browser extensions. Running the app in an incognito window (that doesn't have extensions) won't log any errors.